# t-SNE Python implementation: Kullback-Leibler divergence

Tags: machine-learning, python

t-SNE, as in [1], works by progressively reducing the Kullback-Leibler (KL) divergence, until a certain condition is met.
The creators of t-SNE suggests to use KL divergence as a performance criterion for the visualizations:

> you can compare the Kullback-Leibler divergences that t-SNE reports. It is perfectly fine to run t-SNE ten times, and select the solution with the lowest KL divergence [2]

I tried two implementations of t-SNE:

- **python**: `sklearn.manifold.TSNE()`.
- **R**: `tsne`, from `library(tsne)`.

Both these implementations, when verbosity is set, print the error (Kullback-Leibler divergence) for each iteration. However, they don't allow the user to get this information, which looks a bit strange to me.

For example, the code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
X = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
model = TSNE(n_components=2, verbose=2, n_iter=200)
t = model.fit_transform(X)
```

produces:

```
[t-SNE] Computing pairwise distances...
[t-SNE] Computed conditional probabilities for sample 4 / 4
[t-SNE] Mean sigma: 1125899906842624.000000
[t-SNE] Iteration 10: error = 6.7213750, gradient norm = 0.0012028
[t-SNE] Iteration 20: error = 6.7192064, gradient norm = 0.0012062
[t-SNE] Iteration 30: error = 6.7178683, gradient norm = 0.0012114
...
[t-SNE] Error after 200 iterations: 0.270186
```

Now, as far as I understand, **0.270186** should be the KL divergence. However I cannot get this information, neither from **model** nor from **t** (which is a simple `numpy.ndarray`).

To solve this problem I could:

1. Calculate KL divergence by my self,
2. Do something nasty in python for capturing and parsing `TSNE()` function's output [3].

However:

1. would be quite stupid to re-calculate KL divergence, when `TSNE()` has already computed it,
2. would be a bit unusual in terms of code.

Do you have any other suggestion? Is there a standard way to get this information using this library?

I mentioned I tried *R*'s tsne library, but I'd prefer the answers to focus on the *python* sklearn implementation.

---

References

[1] http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.githubusercontent.com/AlexanderFabisch/1a0c648de22eff4a2a3e/raw/59d5bc5ed8f8bfd9ff1f7faa749d1b095aa97d5a/t-SNE.ipynb

[2] http://homepage.tudelft.nl/19j49/t-SNE.html

[3] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571150/how-to-capture-stdout-output-from-a-python-function-call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TSNE source in scikit-learn is in pure Python. Fit `fit_transform()` method is actually calling a private `_fit()` function which then calls a private `_tsne()` function. That `_tsne()` function has a local variable `error` which is printed out at the end of the fit. Seems like you could pretty easily change one or two lines of source code to have that value returned to `fit_transform()`.

Comment: Essentially what I could do is to set self.error = error at the end of _tsne(), in order to retrieve it from the TSNE instance afterwards. Yes, but that would mean changing sklearn.manifold code, and I was wondering if the developers thought of some other ways to get the information or if not why they didn't (i.e.: is 'error' considered useless by them?). Furthermore, if I changed that code I would need all the people running my code to have the same hack on their sklearn installations. Is that what you suggest, or did I get it wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is what I suggested as a possible solution. Since scikit-learn is open source, you could also submit your solution as a pull request and see if the authors would include that in future releases. I can't speak to why they did or didn't include various things.

Comment: Thanks. If anybody else is interested in this, https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/3422.